# What is the difference (if any) betweeen vim.fn.getcwd() and vim.loop.cwd()?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I saw that the [harpoon2](https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/harpoon/tree/harpoon2) plugin uses [`vim.loop.cwd()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/luvref.html#luvref.txt)  in [here](https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/harpoon/blob/a38be6e0dd4c6db66997deab71fc4453ace97f9c/lua/harpoon/config.lua#L61), and then it got me thinking what is the difference between using [`vim.fn.getcwd()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#getcwd()) and [`vim.loop.cwd()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/luvref.html#luvref.txt).

The following code returns the same path

```
:lua print(vim.fn.getcwd(), vim.loop.cwd())
/Users/rubelagu/git/urllib3 /Users/rubelagu/git/urllib3
```

So it's there any reason to choose one over the other?  To me [`vim.loop.cwd()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/luvref.html#luvref.txt) looks like the "default" choice, so I wonder  why anybody will use [`vim.loop.cwd()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/luvref.html#luvref.txt) instead.

Are they completely equivalent? is there any difference in behaviour, performance, etc in any case?

Comment: I would imagine only the person who wrote the code will be able to answer this question.

Comment: well, I'm using harpoon2 as an example but the question was meant to be general, is there any reason to choose one over the other or they are actually completely equivalent when used without arguments.

Comment: It would be the difference between needing libUV behavior vs. needing vimscript-style `getcwd()` behavior, no (I don't imagine there's a difference, but still)?